# Web Service Handler

Tags: java, android, web-services

My webservice class:

```
public class ConnectionExector {

    private Context context;
    private static final int WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 3000;
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30000;
    protected ExecutorService executorService;
    // to handle thread result
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    // resposes type 
    public enum ResponseType {
        SUCESS, ERROR, TIMEOUT, NULL;
    }

    public class HTTPResponse {
        public ResponseType response = ResponseType.NULL;
        public String value = "";
        public boolean cashed = false;
        public Object data = null;
    }

    public interface onHttpRequestListener {
        public void onHttpResult(HTTPResponse response, String senddata);
    }

    public ConnectionExector(Context context) {

        try {
            this.context = context;

            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class HttpDefs {

        public String _URL;
        public JSONObject jsonData;
        public String _Data;
        public onHttpRequestListener Response;
        public List<NameValuePair> params;

        // public onHttpRequestListener cashResponse = null;

        public HttpDefs(String URL, onHttpRequestListener callback,
                List<NameValuePair> params) {

            Init(URL, callback, params);
        }

        private void Init(String URL, onHttpRequestListener callback,
                List<NameValuePair> params) {

            this.Response = callback;
            this._URL = URL;
            this.params = params;

        }
    }

    public class HttpBackground implements Runnable {
        HttpDefs client;
        String error;

        public HttpBackground(HttpDefs client) {
            this.client = client;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params,
                    CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);
            // HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(null, true);
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(this.client.params,
                    "utf-8");
            if (!paramString.contentEquals(""))
                this.client._URL = this.client._URL;// +"&"+paramString;
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.client._URL);
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.client.params));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            httppost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(
                    CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                String sResponse;

                while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(sResponse);
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                error = "{\"type\":\"error\",\"value\":\"exception\",\"text\":\""
                        + e.getMessage() + "\"}";
                content.append(error);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                error = "{\"type\":\"error\",\"value\":\"exception\",\"text\":\""
                        + e.getMessage() + "\"}";
                content.append(error);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = "{\"type\":\"error\",\"value\":\"timeout\",\"text\":\"Connection Time out\"}";
                content.append(error);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (content == null) {

                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(
                                "{\"type\":\"error\",\"value\":\"timeout\",\"text\":\"Connection Time out\"}");
                    } else if (content.toString().contentEquals("")) {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(
                                "{\"type\":\"error\",\"value\":\"timeout\",\"text\":\"Connection Time out\"}");
                    } else
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(content.toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            httpUI display = new httpUI(jsonObj, this.client);
            handler.post(display);

        }

    }

    class httpUI implements Runnable {

        HttpDefs client;
        String result = " ";
        JSONObject JsonResult;

        public httpUI(JSONObject res, HttpDefs client) {
            this.JsonResult = res;
            this.client = client;
        }

        public httpUI(String res, HttpDefs client) {
            this.result = res;
            this.client = client;
        }

        public void run() {
            HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
            try {
                // JSONObject JsonResult = new JSONObject(this.result);
                String type = "";
                if (JsonResult.has(AppStaticMembers.TAG_status))
                    type = JsonResult.getString(AppStaticMembers.TAG_status);

                if (type.contentEquals("true")) {
                    //
                    if (JsonResult.has("data"))
                        res.data = new JSONTokener(JsonResult.getString("data"))
                                .nextValue();
                    res.response = ResponseType.SUCESS;
                    if (JsonResult.has("message")) {
                        res.value = JsonResult.getString("message");
                    }

                } else {
                    res.response = ResponseType.ERROR;
                }

                if (JsonResult.has("message")) {
                    res.value = JsonResult.getString("message");
                }

                if (client.Response != null) {
                    client.Response.onHttpResult(res, "");

                }

                System.gc();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (this.client.Response != null) {
                    this.client.Response.onHttpResult(res, "");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How I call it:

```
public void SignUp(userdata user, onHttpRequestListener callback) {

        String url = AppStaticMembers.GeneralURL + "Act=" + "signup";
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppStaticMembers.TAG_useremail,
                user.email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppStaticMembers.TAG_username,
                user.username));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppStaticMembers.TAG_userpassword,
                user.password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mob", user.mob));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppStaticMembers.TAG_age, user.age));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regestration", user.regID));
        HttpDefs httpdefs = new HttpDefs(url, callback, params);
        executorService.submit(new HttpBackground(httpdefs));

    }
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could review my code.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't mention anything in particular that you would like people to comment about, I'll make some general remarks regarding the style.

**1)**
Is the name `ConnectionExector` on purpose or just a typo? If you want to shorten the name, it's not a good idea to remove just one letter, just rename it to `ConnectionExecutor`. Check your spelling elsewhere also (e.g. `cashed`)

**2)**

```
public enum ResponseType {
    SUCESS, ERROR, TIMEOUT, NULL;
}
```

This might be personal taste, but I would not name anything `NULL` in Java, as it might suggest its value is just `null` and confuse others who use your code. You could just use the Java `null` value.

```
    public ResponseType response = null;
```

Or just rename it to something like `NONE` or `INIT`.

**3)**

```
public ConnectionExector(Context context) {
    try {
        this.context = context;
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What's the purpose of capturing an exception there? I can see no cases where you would get one, and even if you get one you want the constructor to fail, as the only failure point would be the line

```
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

and if that fails, then your whole instance would be good for nothing.

**4)**

Use Java [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

```
    private void Init(String URL, onHttpRequestListener callback,
```

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

```
class httpUI implements Runnable {
```

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

**5)**

This looks like Android code, so use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) instead of printStackTrace when you catch an Exception.

Comment: Thank you , but my main focus was on how can I post on url throw as httpclient deprecated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be